# Why doesnt the PTS retrieved from gstreamer doesnt match saved ts

Tags: rust, gstreamer, gstreamer-rs

I have a pipeline where I am pulling an rtsp stream from a camera and running some AI detections on it.
I have implemented it in rust but my simplified pipeline looks like the following

```
rtspsrc -> rtspsrc  latency=100 location=rtsp://<rtspurl>  protocols=0x4 name=basesrc basesrc. ! rtph264depay ! tee name=t \
t. ! queue ! vaapidecodebin name=video_decoder ! tee name=decode_t \
   decode_t. ! queue ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=15/1 ! vaapipostproc format=nv12 ! video/x-raw,width=2880,height=1620 ! vaapih265enc ! h265parse config-interval=-1 ! hlssink2 playlist-length=5 max-files=0 target-duration=10 send-keyframe-requests=true program-date-time=true playlist-location=manifest.m3u8 location=video/%t.ts \
   decode_t. ! queue ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=3/1 ! vaapipostproc format=nv12 ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=384 ! videoconvert ! objectdetector ! fakesink async=false
```

objectdetector is my custom plugin which sends a message to the bus when an object is detected. I capture the PTS in its transform_frame_ip() implementation by getting the frame which is of type

```
frame: &mut gst_video::VideoFrameRef<&mut gst::BufferRef>
```

and I get the pts like below

```
let pts = frame.buffer().pts().expect("Buffer must have a PTS value.");
```

However when I try to print all the frame PTS of the TS segment collected by the hlssink element, the PTS times are completely different.

I use the following command to get the PTS of a ts segment.

```
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames -of csv -show_entries frame=coded_picture_number,key_frame,pict_type,pts,pts_time -i <>
```

I am using these PTS values to try to match it with the actual play time so that I can draw the bounding box in a web browser while playing the manifest.

What am I doing wrong? I appreciate any help in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple possible reasons for this:

- The GStreamer PTS is expressed in terms of the GStreamer clock, which is negotiated between the elements when the pipeline is started. When reading a file or receiving a network stream, the corresponding source element translates the incoming PTS into values relative to that negotiated clock. That way if you have multiple sources in your pipeline they all get consistent PTS, even if the incoming streams are unrelated.

  It looks like the RTSP source can add metadata with the original PTS to all buffers if you set its [`add-reference-timestamp-meta`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtsp/rtspsrc.html#rtspsrc:add-reference-timestamp-meta) property, so this might allow you to retrieve the PTS you expect somehow. However,
- RTP also has its own timestamp mechanism independent from the PTS embedded in the TS, and it looks like GStreamer uses those rather than the TS timestamp (see the docs for the [`buffer-mode`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtsp/rtspsrc.html#rtspsrc:buffer-mode) property). You may however be able to retrieve the original PTS from the TS by using the [`emit-stats`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/mpegtsdemux/tsdemux.html#tsdemux:emit-stats) property from the `tsdemux` element that's embedded in your `decode` element.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @jmb. I am using gstreamer 1.20 and I dont think that property is implemented in that version. I am trying out the buffer-mode=0 to use  only the rtp timestamps. However I am not seeing the decodebin or vaapi decoders that expose the `emit-stats` property. How do I set that to emit it?

Comment: `decodebin` is just a wrapper that autodetects the format and builds the corresponding decoding pipeline. Since your input is an MPEG TS, `decodebin` will create a `tsdemux` (and other elements) to decode your stream. Once this is done, you can use [`gst_bin_get_by_name`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstbin.html#gst_bin_get_by_name) or [`gst_bin_get_by_interface`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstbin.html#gst_bin_get_by_interface) to get the `tsdemux` and set its `emit-stats` property.

Comment: Or since you know the format of your input, you can build the corresponding pipeline by hand (you can use [`GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/debugutils.html#GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE) once the pipeline is rolling to see what `decodebin` creates and duplicate it).

Comment: Oh. My source is not a mpegts. It is an rtsp stream. How else can I get that in that case? I will accept your answer though.

Comment: Another thing I noticed was the PTS time difference between what is in the saved TS segment and what we get in the GSTBuffer is always almost one hour.

Comment: RTSP is not a video format, it's a network protocol used to control streaming (not transmit data). It is paired with another protocol (most often RTP, but sometimes plain UDP) for transporting the data. Then each data segment is coded in a video format, which I assume is MPEG TS in your case since you talk about "TS segments".